# Merging two dataframes with different indexation frequencies? (weekly vs. daily)

Tags: python, pandas

I have two datasets in the following format:

The first one is indexed daily:

```
Date              Value
2020-07-01         1
2020-07-02         2
2020-07-03         3
2020-07-04         4
2020-07-05         5
2020-07-06         6
2020-07-07         7
2020-07-08         8
2020-07-09         9
2020-07-10         10
```

and I want to merge it with a dataframe that is indexed by week:

```
Date              Value
2020-07-02         2
2020-07-09         10
2020-07-16         16
```

I want to merge the two dataframes by taking the average of the Value column numbers (first dataframe) starting from the day of the second dataframe (ex: 2nd dataframe starts with 2020-07-02 so I need to take the average of all the values in 2020-07-02 to 2020-07-08 and replace the Date column with 2020-07-02 for that row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `merge_asof`:

```
pd.merge_asof(df,df2.assign(DW=df2.Date), on='Date').groupby('DW').mean()
```

Output:

```
            Value_x  Value_y
DW                          
2020-07-02      5.0      2.0
2020-07-09      9.5     10.0
```